# Working with non ascii characters in array

Tags: matlab

I am working on a program that read text files (utf-8) into a character array and then performs things like, sorting trimming and comparing for equality and so on.

I am not very familiar with the workings of different encodings but I found out that certain characters seems to be stored as 2 characters. (This might not be the correct way to phrase that). What I mean is:
Take this text: `t = 'JOSÉnãodiga'`
When I check `t(4) = 'E'`, `t(5) = '́'` and `t(4:5) = 'É'`

Obviously when I sort the text character by character it messes up these special characters. 
I suppose I have to find a way to be able to switch representation somehow, such that each of these characters becomes one entity (and int for instance), and then do the processing and maybe converting back.

Probably that means changing the specific way in which the file is read and parsed as well.

What I am using to read the files is:

```
function txt = readText(fileName)
textFile = fopen(fileName,'rt'); 
txt = textscan(textFile,'%c');
fclose(textFile);
txt = txt{:,1}';
```

Any help and directions appreciated!

Comment: What about reading the input file as a string?

Comment: Tried that, but ran into the same problems. Can not compare on these special characters. Also sorting and trimming seems less intuitive

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? What is your exact expected output for `t = 'JOSÉnãodiga'` ?

Comment: good question, helps me get my expectations straight. If at all possible I'd like to get some consistent output in the sense that all characters have either 1 or to bytes, so that I may treat them equally. If not ... well work arounds are always possible, but it seems to me this is not unreasonable to wish :)